# TailwindCSS scale class works inconsistently while being used with React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using react and tailwindcss to create a web app for news. Headline of the page looks like the picture below (the image and text were randomly chosen):

[image]

When I hover my mouse on the div the image is supposed to zoom in while changing the state on hover and setting the scale while based on the isMouseIn boolean value. But the problem is that it sometimes works but other times it doesn't. I tried checking the state value and it works perfectly, the values are getting set without any problems but it doesn't scale when I enter the page for the first time. If I refresh the page or change the scale while manually in the code, then it works but otherwise it doesn't. Is this maybe a bug from react or am I doing something wrong?

Check the code down below for a better understanding of my implementation:

```
export default function Headline() {
  /*
   *
   *  green border --> the whole component
   *  orange border --> div that is darkening the whole component
   */

  const [isMouseIn, setMousePos] = useState(false);
  function mouseEnter() {
    setMousePos(true);
  }
  function mouseLeave() {
    setMousePos(false);
  }

  return (
    <div
      onMouseEnter={() => mouseEnter()}
      onMouseLeave={() => mouseLeave()}
      className="mb-[.1em] overflow-hidden 950:rounded-xl cursor-pointer w-[100%] h-[300px] 380:h-[400px] 1215:h-[500px]  max-h-[500px] relative shadow-2xl"
    >
      <img
        src={headline}
        className={`w-full scale-${
          isMouseIn ? "150" : "100"
        } object-cover transition-all duration-700 h-full max-h-full absolute`}
      />
.
.
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

- We can use group modifier of tailwindcss.
- Give "group" class the parent element
- Give class names to child element according to the parent elements state

```js
export default function Headline() {
    return <div
  className="
    group mb-[.1em] overflow-hidden 950:rounded-xl cursor-pointer w-[100%] 
    h-[300px] 380:h-[400px] 1215:h-[500px]  max-h-[500px] relative shadow-2xl"
>
  <img
    src={"https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TEEa.png"}
    className="
    object-cover transition-all duration-700 h-full max-h-full absolute 
    group-hover:scale-150 scale-100"
  />

  </div>;
};
```

##### Referance

- [Tailwind CSS Doc: Group Modifier](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state)